# Openshift SCC for Pod Does Not Get Updated

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I am using openshift 4.8.41, and I tried to provide my simple Deployment (using default SA) with a non-default SCC.

I kept trying various ways to update the SCC, as per the [docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html), e.g.:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user <myscc> -z default
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user <myscc> system:serviceaccount:default:default
oc adm policy add-scc-to-group <myscc> system:serviceaccounts:default
```

But the pod kept having the wrong SCC annotation: `openshift.io/scc: restricted`

How can I update my Deployment or policies to allow my deployment pods to pick up the right SCC?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what would be the best solution to this, but I resolved this issue eventually by adding the capability manually to the deployment, and then `rollout restart` the deployment.

```
...
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    add:
    - NET_BIND_SERVICE
...
```

Thereafter, this capability is added, and the pods weirdly came out with the correct `openshift.io/scc: <myscc>` annotation